# Unable to enter LSI 'web bios'

Tags: raid, ibm, lsi

Attempting to add a new drive to an IBM EXP3000 SAS Storage Enclosure, connected to an IBM x3850 m2. Upon trying to enter the 'webbios' provided by the lsi raid card, it freezes when start is clicked. [image: Example]

This now fails without the new drive, without the old drive, and without the storage enclosure all together. It was working fine a week or two ago, no updates have been performed since.

Is the card dead? I've had a go at finding new firmware, but seemingly after the IBM/Lenovo (merge? purchase?) it seems almost impossible to find suitable firmware or drivers with very little documentation. The server is now running esxi 6, so updating is not proving easy.

Comment: Firmware is really quite easy to find. I have many X series servers with ServRaid controllers (both IBM and Lenovo). I have never had an issue getting firmware updates. Have you tried IBM's global site and search for your machine type 7141?

Comment: @Gmck The IBM 'FixCentral' only provides drivers/firmware compatible with ESX 3.x and 4.x, which are not compatible with my installation of version 6. Others seem to be on dos diskettes - neither I nor the server have a floppy disk drive!

Comment: You can boot a disk image off media other than a floppy disk.

Comment: Is there a reason modern, enterprise updates would be distributed on floppies?